# How to generate WADL file?

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, wadl

I wrote RESTful web service using RESTeasy implementation and turn EJB into JSON. And now I'm on the way of development client side. 
I'm using Netbeans. How I can generate WADL file? And after I would generated client stub without any problem.

Please, could you suggest me how I can do this? Or maybe you know different easy way.

Thanks a lot!
Artem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FYI if you are trying to create a RESTful system, then generating client proxies using WADL will eliminate a significant number of the benefits REST provides.

However, if you are using the term REST as a way to describe a Http API (HAPI) service then go right ahead and use WADL.  I'm not saying this to be pedantic about terminology, I just want you to be aware that, if this the case, you are free to ignore all the "it's not RESTful" because you are not trying to do REST, and that's cool.

If you are trying to make a system where the client and server components can evolve independently over the next 5 to 10 years, then maybe REST is right for you in which case WADL is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks you! I searched that in case using jersey WADL available by link http://localhost:8080/application.wadl (not sure that works for JBoss but for Glasfish yes). Maybe do you know if this i would done for RESTeasy? Google can't answer me(( Thanks one more.