# Has anyone used Enunciate to generate WADL for a RestEasy service?

Tags: resteasy, wadl, enunciate

There are two similar questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301744/can-i-get-application-wadl-file-using-resteasy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297837/how-to-generate-wadl-file) but no adequate answers are given.

I found that I can use [Enunciate](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/getting_started.html) to create WADL for a RestEasy service. So I tried it.

In one of my services I have a method mapped to HTTP GET which I am using like below

```
...
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.Form;
...
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public WebServicePageResponse<D> find(@Form WebServicePageRequest<E> wsPageRequest)
{
    ...
}
```

Enunciate performs a validation on the service methods before it generates the WADL, and throws this error and fails

```
"A resource method that is mapped to HTTP GET must not specify an entity parameter."
```

@Form is a RestEasy specific annotation, while Enunciate can only parse JSR-311 annotations.

Has anyone done something similar? Has anyone successfully used Enunciate to generate documentation for a RestEasy service? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found to this was to remove @Form annotation and use the individual annotations instead ([enter link description here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-688)atleast till Enunciate start supporting this).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a great suggestion for a new feature. [Tracking it here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-688).

It might be an awkward workaround, but have you tried using the [signature override](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Leveraging+Enunciate+Without+JAX-%2aS)?

Comment: thanks, that looks like a neat trick. For now however I have just removed the @Form annotation and replaced it with the individual annotations it was encapsulating.

Comment: I've added my vote to the JIRA - the @Form functionality is really useful in RESTEasy, and the lack of support for it means we can't start using Enunciate.